# Java GUI: Sharing values across different JFrames

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm writing some experimental GUI code. I'm trying to set it up so calling `main` generates two windows, each with a button and a label. The label displays how many times the button has been clicked. However, I want it so if you click the button in one window, the label in the other updates. How would I do this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestGUI extends JFrame {

    private static int count;
    private JButton button = new JButton("odp"); 
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public TestGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(button);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        labelUpdateText();
        add(label);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++;
                labelUpdateText();
            }
        });

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void labelUpdateText() {
        label.setText("Count: " + count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGUI();
        new TestGUI();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

1 - I would rather avoid extending JFrame, since you are not really creating a new class of JFrame.

So instead of having your whole class as a subclass of JFrame ( which is not ) you could create instances of them with out adding more behavior.

2 - If you want to have two labels reflecting the value of a same "thing" you have to **share** that thing between them ( or have someone to update that value for you )

So, using the  famous [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)  you'll need.

- **Model** the counter you want to show in both labels.
- **View** the labels where the model will be shown
- **Controller** Something that deals between them.

They all belong to an application, they are instance attributes of the app.

To see how they fit together I'm pasting here the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;

 // TwoWindows is the Application 
public class TwoWindows {
    // shared state ( model ) 
    private int clickCount = 0;

    // UI
    private List<JLabel> toUpdate = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    // listener ( listens for clicks on buttons kind of controller  )
    private ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

        // Each time update the UI 
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            clickCount++; 
            for( JLabel label : toUpdate ) {
                label.setText( "Count: " + ( clickCount ) );
            }
        }
    };

    // Createsa winddow with a label and a button
    public void showWindow( String named ) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame( named );
        f.add( createButtonAndLabel() );
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible( true );
    }

    // Creates the label and button and adds this.actionListener
    // to each button. 
    private JComponent  createButtonAndLabel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label =  new JLabel("Count: 0");
        JButton clickMe = new JButton("Click me");
        // adding the label to a "view" list.
        toUpdate.add( label );
        // adding the listener to each button 
        clickMe.addActionListener( actionListener );
        panel.add( label );
        panel.add( clickMe );
        return panel;
    }

    // Run the app
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        TwoWindows t = new TwoWindows();
        t.showWindow("A");
        t.showWindow("B");
    }
 }
```

This way you could have a shared model and update as many views as you want.

[alt text http://img387.imageshack.us/img387/1106/capturadepantalla200910d.png](http://img387.imageshack.us/img387/1106/capturadepantalla200910d.png)

Comment: +1 because you use a Mac.  Also the answer is good, but mainly the Mac... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to setup an eventListener and have the buttons fire an event that updates a shared variable (AtomicInteger comes to mind) and update the button text when the event is caught.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by not extending `JFrame` and avoiding mutable statics.

The simplest way to proceed would be to break construction down into phases. Create both labels first. Then construct the rest. Call a constructor method twice for each frame, with the labels as different arguments each time.

More sophisticated is to have a model. The action listener (controller) updates a model, and the model fires a state changed event that a change listener (view) associated with the label in the other frame listens to.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

In the main method:

```
TestGUI a, b;
a = new TestGUI(b);
b = new TestGUI(a);
```

Then add to the constructor:

```
public TestGUI(TestGUI other)
```

And then from either GUI do:

```
other.labelUpdateText();
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. You may want to revise how the instances are associated with each other. The `b` variable cannot be passed to the `TestGUI` constructor before `b` has been instantiated (compiler error: "The local variable b may not have been initialized").

Comment: You could associated the labels like that, but it would create a high coupling between them. Sometimes that's not always desirable.

Comment: Yes, i understand what you mean and this should only be seen as a quick fix to the problem. Oscar Reyes solution below is of course a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

do you really need 2 JFrames?

you could instead have a master and a slave:  one could be the JFrame, the other could be a non-modal dialog.

(non-modal so that it doesn't steal and keep the focus till it is minimized)